# Roots of polynomial in $F_3[x]$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^2 + x + 2 = 0$ in $F_3[x]$. I am asked to show that $x^3 + x + 1$ has roots $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4$.

I started by observing that $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 2 = 0 \implies \alpha^2 = -\alpha - 2 = 2\alpha + 1$. Then $\alpha^3 + \alpha + 1$ is just $\alpha(2\alpha + 1) + \alpha + 1 = 2(2\alpha+1) + \alpha + \alpha + 1 = 6\alpha+3 = 0$.

But when I go to do something similar for $\alpha^2$, I run into some trouble. I know that $\alpha^6 = \alpha+2$ from a previous problem (which I got correct, and it is easily verified). But when I make this substitution into $\alpha^6 + \alpha^2 + 1$, I get $(\alpha + 2) + (2\alpha + 1) + 1 = 1$, not zero. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Surely what you are asked to prove is incorrect? If $x^3+x+1 \in \mathbb F_3[x]$ has $\alpha$ as a root, it must also have its conjugate $\alpha^3$ as a root, and $\alpha^3$ is not in your list of roots.

Comment: Note that the second polynomial has 1 as a root. So either $\alpha^2$ or $\alpha^4 = 1$.

Comment: It's possible I'm being asked to prove something that is incorrect. I'm given the following as an answer:

$0 = (\alpha^3 +\alpha+ 1 )^2 =\alpha^6+\alpha^2+1 = (\alpha^2)^3 +\alpha^2 + 1.$

But this doesn't seem right to me, particularly the step where $(\alpha^3 +\alpha+ 1 )^2 =\alpha^6+\alpha^2+1$.

Comment: Yes, seems like a wrong application of the [freshman's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream#Prime_characteristic).

Comment: Vladhagen, if $\alpha^2 = 1$ then $1 = 2\alpha+1 \implies \alpha = 0$ (contradiction), and $\alpha^4 = 1$ can't be true because $(\alpha^2)^2 = (2\alpha+1)(2\alpha+1) = 4\alpha^2 + 4\alpha + 1 = (2\alpha+1)+\alpha+1 = 2$. So is what I'm being asked to prove incorrect?

Comment: $\alpha^2=-\alpha+1$ and $\alpha^4=-1$; neither of these is a root of $X^3+X+1$.